# image magick command compatibility from shell scripts to python

Tags: python, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I had initially written all the image magic commands in linux environment for executing in shell scripts. But now due to some functionality to be added I have to implement it through python. Will the same command be compatible? If not how do I go about it?

```
#!/bin/sh
for f in `ls *.png`
do
 montage -geometry +0+0 -background skyblue -font /usr/share/fonts/dejavu- lgc/DejaVuLGCSansCondensed-Oblique.ttf -label "$f" $f ./label_added/$f
done
```

And also the following command :

```
convert n255_n2.tif -gravity West -splice 0x18 -annotate +0+2 "x parameter" n255_n3.tif
```

Answer (score 1):

Well. Basically there is similar solution explained in this thread [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12204287/using-imagemagicks-convert-utility-as-a-python-subprocess). You need to launch imagemagick in separate process.

Comment: You can use [JMagick](http://www.jmagick.org/index.html) library which gives Java bindings or spawn another console process like in python example.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import glob
import subprocess

for f in glob.glob('*.png'):
    subprocess.call(['montage', '-geometry', '+0+0', 
                     '-background', 'skyblue',
                     '-font',
                     '/usr/share/fonts/dejavu-lgc/DejaVuLGCSansCondensed-Oblique.ttf',
                     '-label',
                     '"%s"' % f,  f, './label_added/%s' % f])
```